# get time is not member of std

Tags: c++, date, get

aqui alguien si puede ver un error en el codigo que me ayude por su atención gracias
#include

```
std::tm fechaFin = {};

// Obtener la fecha de inicio
std::cout << "Ingrese la fecha de inicio (DD MM AAAA): ";
std::cin >> *std::get_time(&fechaInicio, "%d %m %Y");*
```

estoy haciendo este codigo y me marca error alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cuál error?

Comment: ¿Que versión de c++ estas usando al compilar? ¿Qué compilador estas usando? `get_time` esta disponible a partir de c++11. ¿Estás incluyendo la cabecera correspondiente (`iomanip`)?